# Old Gradle version installed in docker container

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle, docker

I have a docker container in which i am building my projects with jenkins. 
I want **Gradle 3.0** installed in my projects and **java version 1.8.0.91** to make build properly.

When i install gradle with command`apt-get install gradle 3.0` , it runs and start installing, but after that when i check Gradle with `gradle -version` command it says **Gradle 1.5 installed** and Java version also gets changed to "**1.7.0_111**"

i and installing all this on a server running Ubuntu.
I am really stuck at it.

Comment: My advice would be to not even try installing gradle, and use the recommended gradle wrapper instead. That will guarantee that everyone, including the docker container, uses the same gradle version, and automatically downloads and installs it. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: I have a shell script which needed to to be run to build the project, and for that i need gradle installed. @JBNizet

Comment: I tried the same as u said, and i worked fine i just needed to give necessary permissions to my gradle wrapper. Thanks @JBNizet